# How to split 1 row into multiple rows where columns hold same value types

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have a wide dataset which makes it really difficult to manipulate the data in the way I need. It looks like the dummy table below:

[Dummy_table_unsorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmcyn.png)

Essentially, as seen in the table, the information held in 1 row is at a user level, you have a user id and then all the animals owned by each user are in this row. What I would like it, I want this at animal level, so that a user can have multiple entries, which represent each of their different animals. I have pasted a table below of what I would like it to look like:

[Dummy_table_sorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZD2w.png)

Is there a simple way to do this? I have an idea as to how, but it is very long winded. I thought to maybe subset by selected columns relating to one animal only and merge the datasets back together. The problem is, in may data, it is possible for one person to have up to 100 animals, which makes this very long winded.

Please can someone offer a suggestion or a package/command that would allow me to change this wide dataset into a long one?

Thank You.

Comment: Would you please share your sample data and outcome data as code or `dput`. Images can't be copied and pasted into an editor to reproduce the problem. - It's more likely to get an answer, if the community can replicate your problem with a dataset instead of images.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should provide data that someone can easily insert into R.  Screenshots are not helpful and increase the amount of work a person needs to perform to help you.

The data as you have it should be able to be split, and recombined with `bind_rows` or `rbind`.  I would subset the data into three dataframes, rename columns, and bind.  Assuming your original data is called `df`

```
df1 <- df[,c(1:4)]

df2 <- df[,c(1,5:7)]

df3 <- df[,c(1,8:10)]

# rename columns to match
names(df1) <- c('user id', 'animal', 'colour', 'legs')
names(df2) <- c('user id', 'animal', 'colour', 'legs')
names(df3) <- c('user id', 'animal', 'colour', 'legs')

remade <- bind_rows(df1, df2) %>%
  bind_rows(df3)
```